# How to bind nested data in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

net mvc. This is my first project so please be patient. I need to show nested data in asp .net mvc but do not know how to proceed. Here is what I am expected to show:

What I need to show:

[image]

My database structure:

[image]

Here is my database script: 
https:
//drive.google.com/open?id=0B4NHJ4H2YDWxLWUyX0U4ZjhaYkk

Comment: Have you started with anything yet?  There are many tutorials for binding a view to data in ASP .NET MVC, generally using Entity Framework to fetch the data from the database and send the model (or collection of model instances) to the view.  You should probably start with some tutorials.

Comment: And to display in client side, you have very famous `jquery-dataTables` plugin which fits your need..

Comment: I am using entity framework and PagedList for showing data. It is working fine for single database table but I am stuck in above situation.

Comment: You refreshed your edmx file for more tables + you dont have any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved by creating Custom HTMLHelper.